# How do I sort array of pair<int *, int *> in C++?

Tags: arrays, sorting, pointers

I want to sort two pointer arrays after pairing them together.I checked online and found pair sort but its not for pointer arrays.
After pairing them together i want to sort them in ascending order according to the *at array, using any of the sorting methods.
Is this possible in any way?

```
void pairsort(int a[], int b[], int n)
{
 pair<int, int> pairt[n];

 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
 {
     pairt[i].first = a[i];
     pairt[i].second =b[i];
 }
 Sort(pairt,pairt + n)

 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
 {
     a[i] = pairt[i].first;
     b[i] = pairt[i].second;
 }
}


int main()
{
  int n,j;
  int i=0;
  char o1,o2;
  cout<<"Enter total no of processes\n";
  cin>>n;
  int *bt = new int [n];
  int *at = new int[i];
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
      cout<<"\nEnter burst-time of process "<<i+1<<" : ";
        cin>>bt[i];
  }
   cout<<"\nArrival time available(Y/N)\n";
   cin>>o1;
   if(o1=='Y')
   {

       for(i=0;i<n;i++)
       {
           cout<<"\nEnter arrival time of process "<<i+1<<" : ";
            cin>>at[i];
       }

   }
    pairsort(&at, &bt, n);

 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: What you need for sorting is a compare function. This is all about writing the correct compare function.

Comment: @U.Windl I'm still quiet a beginner when it comes to programming...so any ideas?